# How do I create char arrays for string in Turbo C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cin, turbo-c++

Update - Found A Solution.

So Basically, We firstly include string.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Then  we Initialize the array variable:

```
char a[20];
```

Now We'd Use the gets function provided by string.h file:

```
gets(a);
```

Hence forth, It will use cin to take input and then store the value into char array a which is of length of 20.

I'm a school student and in our school these guys teach C++ with "Turbo C++" V3.0 that was released in 90s. I was never into that old school programming and Creating strings is a big Pain in the ass for school projects. I'd love to make these projects with C# or a newer version of C++ but our teachers don't allow that. Hence Forth I gave up on the stackoverflow community to help me.

I want to take input from user using cin and storing the string of text in to char array as that was the most apparent solution as far as I know but I'm struggling to make them.

Here's some code I wrote in the main function:

```
class SpaceWalk {
    public:
        int id;
        char name[];
        char date[];
        char LeadAstronaut[];
        char startingAt[];
        char endingAt[];
};

SpaceWalk spacewalks[1];


spacewalks[0].id = 0;
spacewalks[0].name[] = "Expedition 51";
spacewalks[0].date[] = "May 23, 2017";
spacewalks[0].startingAt[] = "12:20";
spacewalks[0].endingAt[] = "15:06";
spacewalks[0].LeadAstronaut[] = "Peggy Whitson";
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: So far I just made a class like this - class SpaceWalk {
 public:
  int id;
  char name[];
  char date[];
  char LeadAstronaut[];
  char startingAt[];
  char endingAt[];
};

Comment: I can't speak for all of the community, but I don't think I can help you make your school to let you make the projects with another language.

Comment: Please edit your post and show us source code of what you have done and what doesn't work for you. And kindly see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DakshMiglani edit your post and put the code there, not in a comment

Comment: Here we do not have the datatype string, hence forth I've to store them in an array. PS namespaces wasn't available at that time (90s)

Comment: TurboC was made before (and I think even discontinued before) STL was part of the standard. Didn't know anyone was still using it. So I think he's snookered on the STL front.

Comment: updated, my school is still using it.

Comment: @DakshMiglani: Yes you're correct. No namespaces until the 1990s.

Comment: @RichardCritten I know how to write hello world, the problem here is about storing a string into an char array that apparently supports the old school ide Turbo C++

Comment: I think the best thing we can do here is to close to the duplicate - so you can draw your inspiration from that.

Comment: If you are being forced to use TurboC++ and you can't get around it why not build your own implementation of `std::string`?  Since it is for school you don't need anything fancy.  That will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: @user2079303 Sorry, I updated the title.

Comment: @NathanOliver but How ?

Comment: Push back on the school and ask why they're trying to teach something that has no realworld use?  If they say it's cost related, point them to GCC

Comment: @UKMonkey It's India none understands, I tried it a several times. I did point them to gcc and gpp.

Comment: Doesn't STLPort have a version for Turbo C++? See http://www.stlport.org/ You might be in luck, see http://www.stlport.org/doc/platforms.html

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you, I'll see what I can do with stlport.

Comment: @DakshMiglani It's a canonical reference answer for all Turbo C/C++ questions. With a lot of additional information in the answers.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a97b7b58262724e2) is by no means complete but it will show you the start of `std::string`.  Not sure what TurboC++ accepts so I didn't use a member initialization list.

Comment: Thanks again @NathanOliver